# Sort array of arrays by element

Tags: ruby-1.9.3

I want to short this array's arry by second element that is like `"06"` then `` `"00" ``. `"00"` should come first in rows

```
[
    ["new  ", "06"],
    ["one ", "00"],
    ["old  ", "07"],
    ["change  ", "16"] ,
    ["greate ", "08"],
    ["ok  ", "50"],
    ["done  ", "09"]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work out as you want?

```
array.sort { |x,y| x[1] <=> y[1] }
=> [["one ", "00"], ["new  ", "06"], ["old  ", "07"], ["greate ", "08"], ["done  ", "09"], ["change  ", "16"], ["ok  ", "50"]]
```